# Why template is not taken under consideration for specific values?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, type-traits

After reading the following [blog entry at insooth.github.io](https://github.com/insooth/insooth.github.io/blob/master/basic-dependent-typing.md) I rewrote the code to the following form and I was surprised by its results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

template <unsigned d>
using Offset = std::integral_constant<unsigned, d>;

template <int p>
struct Position : std::integral_constant<int, p> {
  static constexpr auto max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

  template <unsigned i>
  constexpr auto operator+(Offset<i>)
      // assertion is equivalent to: value + i <= max
      -> std::enable_if_t<(i <= Position::max - Position::value), Position<Position::value + i>> {
    return Position<Position::value + i>{};
  }
};

int main() {
  {
    auto p = Position<11>{} + 1;
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(p), int>::value, "");
  }

  {
    auto p = Position<std::numeric_limits<int>::max()>{};
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(p), Position<2147483647>>::value, "");
  }

  // this will fail
  // auto poverflow = Position<std::numeric_limits<int>::max() + 1>{};

  {
    auto p = Position<std::numeric_limits<int>::max()>{} + Offset<0>{}; // OK
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(p), Position<2147483647>>::value, "");
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
  }

  {
    //
    // MARKED
    //
    auto p = Position<std::numeric_limits<int>::max()>{} + Offset<1>{}; // OK but shouldn't
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(p), unsigned int>::value, "");
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
  }

  {
    // compiles ok with clang but fails with gcc
    auto p = Position<std::numeric_limits<int>::min()>{} +
      Offset<std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()>{}; // OK but wrong type
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(p), unsigned int>::value, "");
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Last "test" compiles ok with clang 3.9 but fails with gcc 6.2.

live demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61a5bf3040afaadb

Can someone explain why the marked line

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(p), unsigned int>::value, "");
```

compiles -> why `p`'s type is `unsigned int`?

**EDIT**

After small change as [@hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd) suggested, gcc compiles (badly) and clang rejects it.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

template <unsigned d>
struct Offset
{
  static constexpr unsigned value = d;
};

template <int p>
struct Position : std::integral_constant<int, p>
{
  static constexpr auto max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

  template <unsigned i>
  constexpr auto operator+(Offset<i>)
      // assertion is equivalent to: value + i <= max
      -> std::enable_if_t<(i <= Position::max - Position::value), Position<Position::value + i>>
  {
    return Position<Position::value + i>{};
  }
};

int main()
{
  {
    auto p = Position<11>{} + 1;
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(p), int>::value, "");
  }

  {
    auto p = Position<11>{} + Offset<1>{};
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(p), Position<12>>::value, "");
  }

  {
    auto p = Position<std::numeric_limits<int>::max()>{};
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(p), Position<2147483647>>::value, "");
  }

  auto poverflow = Position<std::numeric_limits<int>::max() + 0>{};
  // this would fail
  // auto poverflow = Position<std::numeric_limits<int>::max() + 1>{};

  {
    auto p = Position<std::numeric_limits<int>::max()>{} + Offset<0>{}; // OK now
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(p), Position<2147483647>>::value, "");
    static_assert(!std::is_same<decltype(p), unsigned int>::value, "");
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
  }

  {
    auto p = Position<std::numeric_limits<int>::min()>{} + Offset<0>{}; // OK but wrong type
    static_assert(!std::is_same<decltype(p), unsigned int>::value, "");
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
g++


2147483647
-2147483648


clang


In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1938:44: error: 'basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>' is missing exception specification 'noexcept(is_nothrow_copy_constructible<allocator_type>::value)'
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::basic_string(const allocator_type& __a)
                                           ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1326:40: note: previous declaration is here
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY explicit basic_string(const allocator_type& __a)
                                       ^
main.cpp:57:58: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('Position<std::numeric_limits<int>::min()>' and 'Offset<0>')
    auto p = Position<std::numeric_limits<int>::min()>{} + Offset<0>{}; // OK but wrong type
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:20:18: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with i = 0]: non-type template argument evaluates to 2147483648, which cannot be narrowed to type 'int'
  constexpr auto operator+(Offset<i>)
                 ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:640:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'reverse_iterator' against 'Offset'
operator+(typename reverse_iterator<_Iter>::difference_type __n, const reverse_iterator<_Iter>& __x)
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:1044:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'move_iterator' against 'Offset'
operator+(typename move_iterator<_Iter>::difference_type __n, const move_iterator<_Iter>& __x)
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:1400:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match '__wrap_iter' against 'Offset'
operator+(typename __wrap_iter<_Iter>::difference_type __n,
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3946:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against 'Position'
operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __lhs,
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3959:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'const _CharT *' against 'Position<std::numeric_limits<int>::min()>'
operator+(const _CharT* __lhs , const basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,_Allocator>& __rhs)
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3971:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against 'Offset'
operator+(_CharT __lhs, const basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,_Allocator>& __rhs)
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3982:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against 'Position'
operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __lhs, const _CharT* __rhs)
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3994:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against 'Position'
operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __lhs, _CharT __rhs)
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:4008:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against 'Position'
operator+(basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&& __lhs, const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __rhs)
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:4016:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against 'Position'
operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __lhs, basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&& __rhs)
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:4024:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against 'Position'
operator+(basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&& __lhs, basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&& __rhs)
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:4032:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'const _CharT *' against 'Position<std::numeric_limits<int>::min()>'
operator+(const _CharT* __lhs , basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,_Allocator>&& __rhs)
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:4040:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against 'Offset'
operator+(_CharT __lhs, basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,_Allocator>&& __rhs)
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:4049:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against 'Position'
operator+(basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&& __lhs, const _CharT* __rhs)
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:4057:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against 'Position'
operator+(basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&& __lhs, _CharT __rhs)
^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: @skypjack there's a comment in code about it. Please check it

Comment: Yes, I meant which version. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::integral_constant<T, v>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) supports an implicit conversion to `T`, yielding `v`.

Your custom `operator+` fails during template argument substitution as you intended because of your `std::enable_if_t`, but given that both the LHS `Position<std::numeric_limits<int>::max()>{}` and RHS `Offset<1>{}` support implicit conversions to built-in types, the language's built-in `+` operator can be used. The LHS gets converted to `int`, the RHS gets converted to `unsigned`, and the result gets the type of `int + unsigned`, which is `unsigned`.

Comment: Can we somehow prevent this implicit conversion?

Comment: @Patryk: Sure -- don't derive `Offset<N>` from `std::integral_constant`.

Comment: @Patryk I think that should've been a separate question, but `Position::value + i` is problematic as that too is `int + unsigned`, meaning `unsigned`. Your `Position::value` is negative and `i == 0`, so the result will be outside of `int`'s range, making the conversion back to `int` a narrowing conversion that isn't allowed inside `{}`. It can be tricky to get right if you want to support offsets greater than `INT_MAX`. I suspect you have to convert the offset value to `int`, and if it is outside of `int`'s range, split it up into multiple smaller additions.

Comment: @hvd Well yeah, it's not that easy to handle all possible cases here :/ I think that you've answered my question and I can create a new one if need be. Thanks